# how to parse a python list in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

Consider this simple example

```
tibble(mylist = c("['this is some text from Python!', 'and this is another one!']",
                  "['this is also some cool stuff', 'and this is awesome!']"))
# A tibble: 2 x 1
 mylist                                                        
  <chr>                                                         
1 ['this is some text from Python!', 'and this is another one!']
2 ['this is also some cool stuff', 'and this is awesome!']
```

I would like to parse the python-list-like so that dplyr understand this is a list of sentences (character variables). That is, something like

```
> tibble(mylist = list(list('this is some text from Python!', 'and this is another one!'),
+                      list('this is also some cool stuff', 'and this is awesome!'))) 
# A tibble: 2 x 1
  mylist    
  <list>    
1 <list [2]>
2 <list [2]>
```

How can I do that?
Thanks!

Comment: first it seems your strings are not closed ie they are not valid python lists you should consider closing the strings

Comment: good catch. edited the question, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For valid python values, you could use `reticulate` package:

```
res<- tb %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(mylist=list(reticulate::py_eval(mylist)))

  mylist   
  <list>   
1 <chr [2]>
2 <chr [2]>
```

---

Output:

```
res$mylist
[[1]]
[1] "this is some text from Python!" "and this is another one!"      

[[2]]
[1] "this is also some cool stuff" "and this is awesome!"
```

If you want Exactly similar to your output, then include `as.list`

```
res1<- tb %>%
      rowwise() %>%
      mutate(mylist=list(as.list(reticulate::py_eval(mylist))))%>%
      ungroup()
  mylist    
  <list>    
1 <list [2]>
2 <list [2]>
```

---

```
all.equal(tb_res, res1)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Does

```
tb <- tibble(mylist = c("['this is some text from Python!', 'and this is another one!]",
                        "['this is also some cool stuff', 'and this is awesome!]"))

lapply(tb$mylist, function(pyString) strsplit(gsub("\\]","",gsub("\\[","",pyString)),", ")[[1]])
```

solve your problem?
The idea is as follows: We want to remove the boxed brackets, that can be done via replacing them by an empty character. Note that the `"\\["` and `"\\]"` are needed, since the boxed brackets play a role in regex (keyword: escape characters). Then, we split the string at comma+space, because it looks like this is the python-seperator of lists. Important: If you know that comma+space is also part of the python-strings you want to get, this solution doesn't work.

Comment: What if the string has a comma in it?

Comment: Then it doesn't work. You need to know that there are no commas in the python-string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use read.table() to read in each line, after removing the enclosing brackets.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  mutate(mylist = str_remove(mylist, "^\\["),
         mylist = str_remove(mylist, "]$")) %>% 
  mutate(mylist = map(mylist, ~ as.list(read.table(textConnection(.x),
                                                   sep = ",", quote = "'",
                                                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE))))

# # A tibble: 2 x 1
#   mylist          
#   <list>          
# 1 <named list [2]>
# 2 <named list [2]>
```