# Convert each element in a dataframe which has comma separated values to list in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a column in R dataframe , last column in the picture, it has comma separated values, it is char form. I want to convert it in a list.
For example , i want
`df2$Elementsnew[1]=`

```
[[1]]
[1]0000
[[2]]
[2]0010
```

I have tried the following:

```
    for(i in 1:nrow(df2))
    {
    enter code here
df2$Elementsnew[i] <- as.list(df2$Elementsnew[i],sep=",")

    }
```

But it does not work.
Please help

[image]

Comment: include the data. ie copy the results of `dput(head(your_data))` and paste it here

Comment: this seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65348523/how-to-parse-a-python-list-in-r/65348762#65348762

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
df <- data.frame(elementsnew = c("0000,0010", "1000,1001"))

my.l <- df$elementsnew |> 
    stringr::str_split(pattern = ",") |> 
    list()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).